# Using Response.WriteFile giving access denied error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a website which I 'm developing in asp.net and c#. Currently I have a `GridView` which has 3 columns

1. File Name
2. File Description
3. Download File

I am getting all 3 values from the database. The values are being returned as a `List`. Everything works as expected apart from the download file option. I am using a `ASP:LinkButton` as following

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text="Download" Font-Bold="true" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FileLocation") %>' runat="server" OnClick="DownloadFile"></asp:LinkButton>
```

The full `GridView` code is.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="File Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FileDescription" HeaderText="Description" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Details">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text="Download" Font-Bold="true" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FileLocation") %>' runat="server" OnClick="DownloadFile"></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And the C# code looks like this.

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
    Response.ContentType = ContentType;
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
    Response.WriteFile(filePath);//This line is throwing the error
    Response.End();
}
```

I keep getting an error

```
Access to the path 'My path' is denied.
```

The folder has the correct permissions. If any other part of code is required please let me know. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @CodeCaster It was working before I returned it as a `List` :/ I've added `IIS_IUSER` group to the permission and it's still the same

Comment: That's surely part of the problem. Also what is the actual value of 'FileLocation'?

Comment: @Dura The `FileLocation` is stored in the DB as `C:\Test\Files`

Comment: Well that sounds like a directory, rather than a single file...

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, my bad what I meant was it's stored in that directory

Comment: So what is the *actual value of FileLocation*? I suggest you debug into the code to see what the value really is... certainly how you've *obtained* the value won't change whether or not you can access the file, if you've ended up with the same value.

Comment: @JonSkeet The `FileLocation` `C:\Test\Files\Myfile.docx`

Comment: And that's *definitely* the exact location that's failing, and *definitely* the exact location that was working before? Where did you observe that to be the value? (You should be looking at the value just before the error hits, basically.)

Comment: @JonSkeet It's exactly the same location with the same permission nothing changed at all. Other than how I'm getting the files. Before I was return a single file and now I'm returning a collection of Files

Comment: Again, you haven't said where you observed the value. You should be checking what the value is inside your `DownloadFile` method. If it's the same value that it was before when it was working, that would be very bizarre indeed - but I suspect it's not. You should check it really carefully - check that it doesn't have any extra spaces, check that it's got all the backslashes correctly etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably the fact that you're try to access a directory.

From MSDN doc about your getfilename method

```
string fileName = @"C:\mydir\myfile.ext";
string path = @"C:\mydir\";
string result;

result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    fileName, result);

result = Path.GetFileName(path);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    path, result);

// This code produces output similar to the following: 
// 
// GetFileName('C:\mydir\myfile.ext') returns 'myfile.ext' 
// GetFileName('C:\mydir\') returns ''
```

Are you sure you're actually getting the filename back? or just the directory, like in the second example in the snippet above.

Comment: I'm getting a `FileName` & `Location` from database returned as a `List`. When The user clicks on download button it's meant to pass the filename and allow them to download it

Comment: It's _meant to_. Attach the debugger and check that this actually is the case.

Comment: @CodeCaster The `CommandArgument` value in Debug is `C:\Test\Files`
`

Comment: @Code that's not a **file** path is it?

Comment: @CodeCaster No, it's not, it's weird because before it was return the path :/